# Spring cloud sqs for aws Extended Client Library

Tags: spring, amazon-sqs

It seems that spring cloud aws sqs does not support the aws sqs Extended Client Library.

When I sent message to queue, Spring sqsListener can not handle the meaasge which like this:

`["com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.MessageS3Pointer",{"s3BucketName":"locker-life-edi-data-file-from-sqs-dev","s3Key":"f7777cab-00ba-4a8d-8bf4-a74b4fc8cf77"}]. MessageAttribute :"SQSLargePayloadSize" -> "{StringValue: 300000,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],DataType: Number}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Add AWS extended SQS client library support in Spring AWS Cloud](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/167)**

There is an open GitHub issue for this very feature, however it hasn't gotten much traction yet.  You can leverage the Extended Client Library directly in your project.  That's as good as it will get until this feature is implemented.

I'm sure Pull Requests are welcome though.